# DataTables - Reduce column a little?

Tags: css, datatables

I use DataTables and would like to reduce the columns a bit.

I use the following code for this.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [
    { "width": "29px", "targets": 0 }
  ]
});
```

When I then check the number of pixels in the developer tools in Chrome, significantly more pixels appear and I still have too much space between the last letter of the column name and the arrow for sorting. See screenshot.

I just want to reduce the space between the last letter of the label and the arrow for sorting the records a bit. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULd5E.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this solution but maybe it's working. We need to define width of table with this option.
Datatable configutation :

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "autoWidth": false
} );
```

Css :

```
table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed; // ***********add this
  word-wrap:break-word; // ***********and this
}
```

OR

You can try from this link: https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/size_fixed.html